# Problem adding onclick listener on Google-Maps-Chart using the google.ChartWrapper

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-visualization

i have a problem with adding an onclick event listener on the Google Maps Chart, using the google.visualization.ChartWrapper in Angular 7

The event doesn't work and i don't get any errors or Logs. The map wil draw fine and the 'ready' listener also works like a charm.

the official documentation : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject

```java
//My Html-Element

<div id="chart"></div>

//I Initilize the ChartWrapper

map: google.visualization.ChartWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'Map',
  dataTable: [["Latitude", "Longitude", "Name"], [lat, long, company]],
  options: {
    showTooltip: true,
    enableScrollWheel: true,
    useMapTypeControl: true,
    tooltip: { isHtml: true }
  },
  containerId: 'chart'
});

//In NgOnInit im loading the package and call my draw function
ngOnInit() {

    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['map'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawMap.bind(this));

}

drawMap() {
//I set the ready eventlistener

google.visualization.events.addListener(this.map,'ready',this.onReady.bind(this));   
this.map.draw();

}

onReady() {
//This Event works and i get the alert
  alert('Ready');
google.visualization.events.addListener(this.map.getChart(), 'click', this.onClick);
}

onClick($event) {
    //This never works
    alert('Click'); 
}
```

I hope anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [events documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#events) for the `Map` chart,
there is not a `'click'` event.

try using `'select'` instead...

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(this.map.getChart(), 'select', this.onClick);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the 'select' event is only triggered when clicking markes or places already existing. But i actually need the latitude and longitude of every click.

Comment: you wanted to know why the click event didn't work, it doesn't exist...